# Moving a VB6 Application from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2014

Tags: vb6, sql-server-2000, sql-server-2014

Interested to know if anyone has had any experience with moving a VB6 application from SQL Server 2000 to a newer version of SQL Server.

1. There are VB6 legacy apps on a Windows 2000 Server
2. These VB6 apps connect to a SQL 2000 Database
3. We are looking to upgrade from SQL 2000 to SQL 2014
4. We are reporting with Crystal Reports
5. The VB6 apps have inline SQL within them

I'd like to understand what the possible implications could be?

Thanks

Comment: ADODB is capable of connecting to everything from SQL 2000 through SQL 2014. We have a legacy app that still runs that connects to whatever SQL instance the user has, and several have moved to 2014. I think your question is a little vague and will most likely be closed for being Unclear unless you [edit] it with some specifics.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, there is no direct migration path from 2000 to 2014. This article (http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2014/sql-select-steps-migrate-sql-server-2000-sql-server-2014) outlines some potential steps to take to perform the upgrade.

Things that may trip you up not mentioned in this article:

1. DTS no longer exists so if you have any DTS packages, it will be a project to upgrade/convert them all over to SQL Server Integration Serices (SSIS) packages.
2. If your VB6 app contains hard coded SQL statements, rather than just calling stored procedures, you could have minor syntax issues that would have to be rectified (so test EVERYTHING)
3. If you are also looking to migrate VB6 to .NET, there is an upgrade wizard out there somewhere, but it is HORRIBLE, so depending on the need, it may be faster to just re-write from scratch. If you are implying that the VB6 application would just connect to the migrated 2014 database, the note on the main question is accurate, but again...test EVERYTHING.

3a. If you are referencing any old COM components or old OCX controls, it will be a source of pain.

3b. Does your app do any reporting? old 2000 SSRS, or Crystal reports? again, another project.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Jeremy! The VB6 apps do contain inline SQL, we don't need to worry about DTS thankfully, we won't look to upgrade from VB6 to .NET directly as the code architecture isn't great, we are referencing old OCX components and the app does reporting with Crystal Reports.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it, and there were stored procedures / user functions that needed to be updated for compatibility. Here is a Microsoft tool, [SQL Server Upgrade Advisor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144256(v=sql.120).aspx). If you are using inline SQL in your code I'm not sure if this tool will help you. I was fortunate in that most on teh application SQL was implemented as stored procedures inside the database itself.

Here is an [MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mspfe/archive/2012/12/06/sql-server-upgrade-advisor-considerations-when-upgrading-from-sql-2000-to-sql-2012.aspx) about upgrade considerations and using the Upgrade Advisor tool.

Comment: Thanks Jac! There's a lot of inline SQL so it might be a nightmare! Thanks for the links!!